# Titanium TabGroup: How to close window and then display the tab Group?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I have following flow of app :

First screen is Login screen and if Login gets success the tab-group opens.

here is code :

**app.js**

```
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow
({
    title:'User Login',
    url:'Login.js',
    tabBarHidden:true,
    backgroundColor:'gray',
    navBarHidden:false
});
win.open();
```

**Login.js**

```
var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

// some UI controls

loginBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e)
{
   //calling web service     
   if(isSuccess == 1)
   {
       var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup();    
       // code to create Tab 
       tabGroup.open();   
   }
}
```

Now if I hide the **currentWindow (win)** every thing works fine But Login view is get displayed in background of all the time !!! So I want to close Login window and then open the tab group. So I tried :

```
win.close();
tabGroup.open();
```

But doesn't work application gets crashed.

So, How to close window and then display the tab Group ???

Thanks....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved !!! As slash197 has suggested in **Login.js** I was trying to close `win` which was the root window. So I used a dummy window inside the **Login.js** and close it and the open `tabGroup` . Like :

**Login.js**

```
var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
var loginView = Ti.UI.createWindow
({
    backgroundColor:'transparent'
});
```

And added all the UI component into the `loginView` instead of `win`.

Then for **Android**

```
loginView.open();
```

And for **iPhone**

```
loginView.open();
win.add(loginView);
```

After success :-

```
loginBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e)
{
   //calling web service     
   if(isSuccess == 1)
   {
       var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup();    
       // code to create Tab 

       //for Android
       loginView.close();

       //for iPhone
       win.remove(loginView);

       tabGroup.open();   
   }
}
```

**Note:-** Not sure that it is best approach. But it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

If that window is the first than it's the root element and can't be closed. You could try removing all of it's children and set it's background to transparent then open your `tabGroup`.

Comment: @adrian aproape de tine, Targu Mures